# Error with running react on Mac succesfully: ELIFECYCLE, spawn, ENOENT

Tags: reactjs, npm, compiler-errors

I was able to run the create-react-app to create a successful tester react file. However, when I try to run ANY react file with "npm start", I get the following errors:

```
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! react1-complete-guide--scripts-version@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react1-complete-guide--scripts-version@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
```

I tried putting HOST = "localhost" and I think I removed the node modules folders properly, but still have not been successful. Can someone provide some guidance/commands to help, please? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `npm` does not find `react-scripts` in dependencies.
Try removing everything in `node_modules` folder, remove `package-lock.json` file. Then run `npm install` to reinstall all dependencies.